# Best way to execute jobs on runners using tags?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

This is one of my jobs in my .gitlab-runner.yml:

```
test-prod:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - vm1

  script:
    - pwd
```

If I add to `tags` tag `vm2`(which is a tag of another runner) it won't work because it will look for a runner with both tags.

So how do I configure the job to execute the `script` on each runner separately (meaning that if I have 3 runners with seperate single tags: vm1, vm2 and vm3 it will execute the script on each runner).

I tried adding the same tag on every runner but that only executes the script on one runner of that tag randomly.

I know I can add another `test-prod` with a different tag but isn't there a simpler and easier way?

Comment: By design, runners are decoupled from jobs. Jobs are meant to 'run once', and ideally it shouldn't matter where (in which runner) they run. Moreover, runners are (ideally) stateless. From your question, it is not clear what is that you are trying to do. Perhaps you could add more context.

Comment: "more context" Agreed. Why exactly do you want to "execute the [same!] script on each runner"? If it's about different Runner configurations, you could instead try to move those config differences into a `parallel:matrix` job (see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallelmatrix) or let the matrix assign the tags, see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#select-different-runner-tags-for-each-parallel-matrix-job (as 
VonC reply below).

Answer (score 3):

The use of the `extends` keyword in GitLab CI/CD indeed provides a way to share configurations between jobs, but like you mentioned, if you have many tags, it could become tedious to manage.

Based on your requirements of wanting to simplify the `.gitlab-ci.yml` and having the system choose a free runner dynamically based on the tag, the [matrix feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallelmatrix) would be more suitable.

- Using matrix jobs allows you to define the core job only once, then dynamically instantiate it for different runners. That makes the configuration more maintainable.
- Matrix jobs are individual jobs; they will each get queued and execute on the next available runner that matches the tag. Therefore, they meet your requirement for default functionality in choosing a free machine.

See also as illustration:

- "**[GitLab CI — Parallel with Matrix](https://yashwanth-l.medium.com/gitlab-ci-parallel-with-matrix-7bd3acca8f70)**" from [Yashwanth Lakkaraju](https://twitter.com/encipherrun03), Jan. 2023
- "**[Efficient pipelines in GitLab CI/CD: Parallel Matrix Builds + `!reference`](https://dnsmichi.at/2021/09/23/efficient-pipelines-gitlab-ci-cd-parallel-matrix-builds-reference/)**" from [Michael Friedrich](https://twitter.com/dnsmichi), Sept. 2021

Plus, you can [select different runner tags for each parallel matrix job](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#select-different-runner-tags-for-each-parallel-matrix-job) (GitLab 14.1+, Jul. 2021)

You can use the `parallel: matrix` feature to dynamically create jobs based on variables, and use those variables to dynamically select runners through the `tags` keyword.

```yaml
test-prod:
  stage: test
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - VM_TAG: [vm1, vm2, vm3]
  tags:
    - ${VM_TAG}
  script:
    - pwd
```

That would create separate jobs for `vm1`, `vm2`, and `vm3`, directly using the `parallel: matrix` feature for dynamic runner selection.
Each dynamically created job will have a tag derived from the `VM_TAG` matrix, ensuring that each job runs on a runner with the corresponding tag. That fulfills your requirement of having the system choose a free machine dynamically based on the tag.

---

> I got the dropdown list with `test-prod: [vm1]`, `test-prod: [vm2]`, and `test-prod: [vm3]` items.
> But I want only one button: `test-prod`.

I am not aware of a built-in feature that allows you to run a single job on multiple runners with different tags, while also presenting it as a single pipeline job in the GitLab UI. The matrix feature will inevitably create multiple jobs in the dropdown.

However, there is a workaround you could consider: use a "parent" job to trigger "child" pipeline jobs programmatically via GitLab's API.

The parent job would appear as a single button in the UI, while the child jobs would execute on different runners based on their tags. That way, when you press the "`Run Pipeline`" button, it will initiate this parent job, which in turn would trigger the other jobs to run on runners with tags `vm1`, `vm2`, and `vm3`.

A simplified example of what the parent job might look like:

```yaml
trigger-multiple-runners:
  stage: trigger
  script:
    - >
      for tag in vm1 vm2 vm3; do
        curl --request POST \
             --form "token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN" \
             --form "ref=master" \
             --form "variables[TAG]=$tag" \
             "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/trigger/pipeline";
      done
```

And then the child pipeline `.gitlab-ci.yml` could look like:

```yaml
test-prod:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - ${TAG}
  script:
    - pwd
```

That is a bit more involved and requires you to handle API calls, but it would give you the single-button behavior you are looking for, while still allowing jobs to run on different tagged runners. Note that you will need to replace `https://gitlab.example.com` and other placeholders with your actual GitLab instance information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. These changes only optimized code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/58493305/10617148 answer. I got the dropdown list with `test-prod: [vm1]`, `test-prod: [vm2]`, and `test-prod: [vm3]` items. But I want only one button `test-prod`.

Comment: @VasylNahuliak What do you mean by "These changes only optimized code from stackoverflow.com/a/58493305/10617148 answer"? And when you said: "I got the dropdown list with...", is it after testing the matrix approach?

Comment: stackoverflow.com/a/58493305/10617148 - https://i.ibb.co/1bZpykZ/SCR-20230831-npoa.png ;
your solution - https://i.ibb.co/2dNYKyf/SCR-20230831-npja.png

Comment: Could you add screenshots for your answer?

Comment: @VasylNahuliak Do you mean the screenshots you mentioned in your past comment?

Comment: you updated your answer so you tried it yourself? I wonder what this result will look like. Thanks

Comment: @VasylNahuliak No it is just a suggestion, for you to try out.

Comment: It's not working, and very hard to reproduce. I guess this is not for https://stackoverflow.com/q/58488097/10617148 answer.

Comment: @VasylNahuliak OK. Hopefully your bounty will attract a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to do with this, but you can solve it this way using the [extend function](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends):

```
.test-prod:
  stage: test
  script:
    - <do your stuff>

test-prod:vm1:
  extends: .test-prod
  tags:
  - vm1

test-prod:vm2:
  extends: .test-prod
  tags:
  - vm2

test-prod:vm3:
  extends: .test-prod
  tags:
  - vm3
```

Comment: This approach works but it is inconvenient because it has a lot of different tags I do not want to copy & paste a lot of jobs. Also, I want default functionality choosing the free tag's machine.

Answer (score -1):

If you have separate runners tagged as vm1, vm2, vm3, etc., and you want a job to run on each runner separately without copying and pasting multiple job definitions, the simplest approach would be to use a script to generate the .gitlab-ci.yml file.

```
tags = ["vm1", "vm2", "vm3"]

with open(".gitlab-ci.yml", "w") as f:
    for tag in tags:
        f.write(f"""
test-prod-{tag}:
    stage: test
    tags:
        - {tag}
    script:
        - pwd
""")
```

Execute this script every time you wish to update the CI/CD pipeline.